# Protected Routes - react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am following [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/) to implement protected routes, however, I am getting a very weird bug.

Depending on how I write my conditional, the component doesn't get re-rendered. Below is the code:

```
export const LoginRequired = ({ isAuthenticated, children }) => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to='/' replace /> // isAuthenticated state changes detected
        // return children <- isAuthenticated state changes not detected
    }
    // return <Navigate to='/' replace /> <- isAuthenticated state changes not detected
    return children; // isAuthenticated state changes detected
}
```

I want the children to be rendered if `isAuthenticated` is true. However, when I have that block of code uncommented, the state changes aren't detected.

I'm not too sure why this is not working as I have the exact same code for a different route.

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, children }) => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to='/' replace />
    }
    return children;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is you need to add a not (!) operator in front of the isAuthenticated variable.

I would also recommend changing the Navigate component and use a useNavigation hook instead. This is typically preferred unless in a class component where you cant use hooks.

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, children }) => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();
    if (!isAuthenticated) { //Check not authenticated
         navigate("/", { replace: true });
    }
    return children;
}
```

Comment: Hello, that doesn't work. Did you mean ```useNavigate```? If so, there is no method ```replace``` even with that.

Comment: My bad I was using React-Navigation v6 off the top of my head. Edited

Comment: The issue is that they aren’t using the ! Not about a useNavigation hook. I would recommend editing your answer to focus on what the solution really is

Comment: @RichardHpa I updated it to make myself more clear